# Byte Length of List of Integers

Tags: c#, arrays, integer, byte

I have this List of integers { 20, 40 } and I want to get the length of the total number of bytes in the list

So since there are two integers, each integer is 4 bytes, therefore the total length of bytes in this case is 8.

If there was 3 integers the answer would be 12.

My idea was to loop through each integer and get the byte of the each integer using Bitconverter but I can't seem to append to the byte array.

```
var bytes = new byte[] { };
foreach (var num in nums)
{
  bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);

}
```

Then we would get the length of the bytes array but this method just does 1 value.

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't a simple mathematical exercise of `nums.Count() * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @Llama yeah you're right didn't really think about that, thanks

Comment: Technically the amount of memory that a list uses is based on the size of the internal array which can actually be larger than the number of items currently in the list.

Comment: @juharr fortunately, you can get that size from `nums.Capacity` (multiplied by `sizeof(int)`)

Answer (score 2):

If you *just* want the number of bytes: `sizeof(int) * nums.Count` (or `sizeof(int) * nums.Capacity` if you want the size of the oversized backing array).

Assuming you want the data:

You can't use `BitConverter` to *append* bytes; you *could* copy each in turn, but honestly, that's not a good idea; you *could* loop applying offsets and using other APIs to write into the existing buffer, but - other tools exist; consider:

```cs
var nums = new List<int> { 20, 40 };
var arr = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, byte>(CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(nums)).ToArray();

// this is just a lazy way of showing the output
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(arr));
```

Note that this is CPU-endian; if you need it to work identically on all CPUs, you'll need to use an endian-aware approach, for example `BinaryPrimitives`. For example:

```cs
byte[] arr = new byte[sizeof(int) * nums.Count];
var span = new Span<byte>(arr);
foreach (var num in nums)
{
    BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(span, num);
    span = span.Slice(4);
}
```